# How do you get the last inserted ID from a class into a redirect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lastinsertid

I use the following code to insert data into mysql with php pdo (from a class):

```
$this->pdo = $this->connectMySql();
        if(isset($params['content'])){
            $query = 'INSERT INTO pages SET menu_name = :menu_name, position = :position, visible = :visible, content = :content, pagetype = :pagetype';
        }else{
            $query = 'INSERT INTO pages SET menu_name = :menu_name, position = :position, visible = :visible, pagetype = :pagetype';
        }
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':menu_name',$params['menu_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  // PDO::PARAM_STR is used for treating 
        $stmt->bindParam(':position',$params['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':visible',$params['visible'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if(isset($params['content'])){
            $stmt->bindParam(':content',$params['content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }else{}
        $stmt->bindParam(':pagetype',$params['pagetype'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            return false;
        }
        $lastid = $this->pdo->lastInsertId();
        $this->pdo = null;
        return $lastid;
```

It is inside a try catch block. The insert works, but I would like to get the last id inserted, I have used the following (u can see part of it up here), but on the index.php page I don't seem to get the id:

```
$params = array(
            'menu_name' => $_POST['menu_name'],
            'position' => $_POST['position'],
            'visible' => $_POST['visible'],
            'content' => $_POST['editor1'],
            'pagetype' => $_POST['pagetype']
            );
if ($pages->insertPage($params)) {
    $html->redirect_to("content.php?pageid=" . $pages->lastid);
}else{
    $message = "Aanmaken van pagina is niet gelukt!";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I don't see why this is a duplicate. I have seen that other question but that's about storing the lastinsertid into the database (probably not even within a class). 
On my main page (index.php) I call an insert function (from a class) and when inserted it should return the id to the main page. I even tried to change the code (to get and return the lastinsertid) from the other post, but all I get is an empty value.

Comment: @Naveen Programmer, as you can see I use pdo, I don't want to use mysql_insert_id.

Answer (score -1):

you call lastid like it's a method, on index.php:9
I think $pages->lastid would be better

Comment: as stated above (my edit), I don't think this is a duplicate, because it is slightly different from the other question. Because the other question is about saving the lastinsertid into the database, I want to return the id to the index.php in the header location as redirect.